# Flutter 2.0 - Autocomplete widget goes out of screen from right side

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0

How do I make the autocomplete box be the same size with the `TextField` which doesn't have a specific width, it takes up the maximum width.

```
              Autocomplete(
                optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                  if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                    return ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
                  }
                  return ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
                      .where((String option) {
                    return option
                        .toString()
                        .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                  });
                },
                onSelected: (option) {
                  print(option);
                },
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: @Andrej you can try with the  flutter doc on autocomplete.. Add `Padding` to the `AutocompleteBasicExample()` widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html

Comment: I tried it, and `Padding` broke it. That is probably a bug.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug

Answer (score 44):

I got the same problem while trying to make my own autocomplete widget based on RawAutocomplete and I used a layout builder to get the perfect container width size inside my optionsViewBuilder:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => RawAutocomplete<String>(
    focusNode: focusNode,
    fieldViewBuilder: fieldViewBuilder,
    optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) => Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(4.0)),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 52.0 * options.length,
          width: constraints.biggest.width, // <-- Right here !
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemCount: options.length,
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final String option = options.elementAt(index);
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () => onSelected(option),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(option),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) =>
        suggestions.where((element) => element.contains(textEditingValue.text.trim().toUpperCase())),
    textEditingController: controller,
  ),
)
```

Result:
[Expected result on my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X46Gk.png)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this issue a lot too, and the options builder is very specific about where it wants the size or padding to be placed in the hierarchy. Here's my working example:

```dart
optionsViewBuilder: (context, onAutoCompleteSelect, options) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
       child: Material(
         color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
           elevation: 4.0,
           // size works, when placed here below the Material widget
           child: Container(
              // I have the text field wrapped in a container with
              // EdgeInsets.all(20) so subtract 40 from the width for the width
              // of the text box. You could also just use a padding widget
              // with EdgeInsets.only(right: 20)
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                child: ListView.separated(
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   itemCount: options.length,
                   separatorBuilder: (context, i) {
                     return Divider();
                   },
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     // some child here
                   },
                 )
              ),
           )
        );
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78746#issuecomment-925535777), at the time of writing this, the best option seems to be to alter the `BoxConstraints` width and height included in the default `_AutoCompleteOptions` code (that can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/33403bd28ee09632d4a08f82d0ed0d8b2490d3c8/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/autocomplete.dart#L153)), and pass it as the `optionsViewBuilder` argument of `Autocomplete`.
This requires that you are able to calculate the required width in advance, though.

Pasting my code, just for reference:

```
Autocomplete<Animal>(
  optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) {
    if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
      return const Iterable<Animal>.empty();
    }
    return animalsList.where((Animal option) {
      return "${option.id}".contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()) ||
          option.nome!.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()) ||
          option.ownerCF!.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
    });
  },
  optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 600), //RELEVANT CHANGE: added maxWidth
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: options.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Animal option = options.elementAt(index);
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  onSelected(option);
                },
                child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  final bool highlight = AutocompleteHighlightedOption.of(context) == index;
                  if (highlight) {
                    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                      Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, alignment: 0.5);
                    });
                  }
                  return Container(
                    color: highlight ? Theme.of(context).focusColor : null,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(option.getInfo() + " - " + option.getOwnerInfo()),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  displayStringForOption: (option) => option.getInfo() + " - " + option.getOwnerInfo(), 
  onSelected: (option) => selected = option,
);
```

Comment: But how to calculate the required width in advance. `maxWidth = 600` doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan I chose it by eye, because it was a good enough measure for my app and the content of my AutoComplete. I know it's not the best approach: you can wrap the AutoComplete in a LayoutBuilder to know the available space at runtime and then decide which size will fit best your scenario

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and resolved it by using a `ValueListenableBuilder`.

The width of `Material` widget is depends on width of the widget returned by `field ViewBuilder` (default is a `TextFormField`), so one solution is get  width of `TextFormField` after one frame completed and notify your custom `optionsViewBuilder`

sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AutocompleteText extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AutocompleteTextState();
}

class AutocompleteTextState extends State<AutocompleteText> {
  final ValueNotifier<double?> optionsViewWidthNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);

  static const List<User> _userOptions = <User>[
    User(name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@example.com'),
    User(name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@example.com'),
    User(name: 'Charlie', email: 'charlie123@gmail.com'),
  ];

  static String _displayStringForOption(User option) => option.name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Autocomplete<User>(
        displayStringForOption: _displayStringForOption,
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
          if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
            return const Iterable<User>.empty();
          }
          return _userOptions.where((User option) {
            return option
                .toString()
                .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
          });
        },
        onSelected: (User selection) {
          print('You just selected ${_displayStringForOption(selection)}');
        },
        fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            TextEditingController textEditingController,
            FocusNode focusNode,
            VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
          return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              optionsViewWidthNotifier.value =
                  (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.width;
            });
            return TextFormField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                onFieldSubmitted();
              },
            );
          });
        },
        optionsViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<User> onSelected,
          Iterable<User> options,
        ) {
          return ValueListenableBuilder<double?>(
              valueListenable: optionsViewWidthNotifier,
              builder: (context, width, _child) {
                return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: width,
                      height: 200.0,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        itemCount: options.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          final User option = options.elementAt(index);
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              onSelected(option);
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Text(_displayStringForOption(option)),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    optionsViewWidthNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

@immutable
class User {
  const User({
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String email;
  final String name;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name, $email';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) {
      return false;
    }
    return other is User && other.name == name && other.email == email;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(email, name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the only solution here which works without requiring modifying the underlying dependency code, or hardcoding widths. Worked well for me (I'm using [chips_input](https://pub.dev/packages/chips_input/versions/0.0.4) which wraps the autocomplete widget). I know it's a bit of a hack but I'll take it. Fingers crossed they fix the [underlying bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78746).

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I just had to wrap the widget that I'm returning in `optionsBuilder` in an `Align`. After doing that, it started working as intended, creating the menu under the input field without stretching out of the screen. I have also used `LayoutBuilder`'s `constraints.maxWidth` to define the menu's width.

Example:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return RawAutocomplete<String>(
      optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: options.map((e) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text(e));
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have seen source code `autocomplete.dart`, there is missing parameter width, but height exists, I have added width by hand, and it worked.

```
class Autocomplete<T extends Object> extends StatelessWidget {
/// Creates an instance of [Autocomplete].
const Autocomplete({
Key? key,
required this.optionsBuilder,
this.displayStringForOption = RawAutocomplete.defaultStringForOption,
this.fieldViewBuilder = _defaultFieldViewBuilder,
this.onSelected,
this.optionsMaxHeight = 200.0,
this.optionsMaxWidth = 285.0 // I added this line
this.optionsViewBuilder,
this.initialValue,

/// The default value is set to 200.
final double optionsMaxHeight;
final double optionsMaxWidth; // Added this line

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return RawAutocomplete<T>(
  displayStringForOption: displayStringForOption,
  fieldViewBuilder: fieldViewBuilder,
  initialValue: initialValue,
  optionsBuilder: optionsBuilder,
  optionsViewBuilder: optionsViewBuilder ?? (BuildContext context, AutocompleteOnSelected<T> onSelected, Iterable<T> options) {
    return _AutocompleteOptions<T>(
      displayStringForOption: displayStringForOption,
      onSelected: onSelected,
      options: options,
      maxOptionsHeight: optionsMaxHeight,
      maxOptionsWidth: optionsMaxWidth, // Added this line
    );
  },
  onSelected: onSelected,
);
}


// The default Material-style Autocomplete options.
 class _AutocompleteOptions<T extends Object> extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AutocompleteOptions({
  Key? key,
  required this.displayStringForOption,
  required this.onSelected,
  required this.options,
required this.maxOptionsHeight,
required this.maxOptionsWidth // Added this line
}) : super(key: key);

final AutocompleteOptionToString<T> displayStringForOption;

final AutocompleteOnSelected<T> onSelected;

final Iterable<T> options;
final double maxOptionsHeight;
final double maxOptionsWidth;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: Material(
    elevation: 4.0,
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: maxOptionsHeight, maxWidth: maxOptionsWidth), // Added maxWidth which was missing here
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: A constant width of 285? How can it work in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug for Autocomplete widget, the bug is being tracked here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78746

So the only solution at the moment is to create your own customized widget. I wrote my own widget and published as a package for reuse and is also being maintained.

you can find it here: https://pub.dev/packages/searchfield

Answer (score 1):

Still happen in flutter 3.3.5 ...

My workaround is wrapping the `Autocomplete` inside a `LayoutBuilder` and using the `constraints.maxWidth` to set the width for the `optionsViewBuilder`'s ListView.

The detailed snippet is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78746#issuecomment-1326488333

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the whole **Autocomplete** widget in a sized box?
If the sizing widgets are not working this probably maybe a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just do like default builder source, and it just work property. I think it's error happened because not has parent config.

```
optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.r),
          child: Container(
            width: 100.r,
            height: 100.r,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: context.oldTheme.lightGrey,
                )),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(
                  options.toList()[index],
                  style: context.oldTheme.textTheme.body2,
                );
              },
              itemCount: options.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
```