# RawAutoComplete initialValue not setting in Flutter

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I was able to get initialValue to work in AutoComplete. But there is a bug where the drop down goes off screen. So I found a workaround on slack and I am not using RawAutoComplete and trying to get the initial Value to work. I tried to set it in RawAutoComplete with:

```
child: RawAutocomplete<String>(
            initialValue: TextEditingValue(text: itemTypeController.text),
```

When I look at the documentation I see:

> This parameter is ignored if [textEditingController] is defined

But I am not sure how to set it otherwise.

I initially tried to set it in the TextFormField like so:

```
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: itemTypeController,
          initialValue: "test",
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Item type*",
            hintText: 'What is the item?',
          ),
        ),
```

But that throws this error:

> 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.

Which I assume is because if controller is present it woudl take the initial value from there. If both are not null then it doesnt know what to pic. I need the controller because I need to retrieve the value in the form to submit to my database.

Full code below:

```
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => InputDecorator(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.style),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        child: RawAutocomplete<String>(
            initialValue: TextEditingValue(text: itemTypeController.text),
            // first property
            optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
              if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                return itemTypeList;
              }
              return itemTypeList.where((String option) {
                return option
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
              });
            },

            //second property where you can limit the overlay pop up suggestion
            optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
                Iterable<String> options) {
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 200.0,
                    // set width based on you need
                    width: constraints.biggest.width * 0.8,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      itemCount: options.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            onSelected(option);
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(option),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },

            // third property
            fieldViewBuilder:
                (context, controller, focusNode, onEditingComplete) {
              itemTypeController = controller;

              return Focus(
                onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                  if (temperatureItemTypes
                      .contains(itemTypeController.text.trim())) {
                    //show temperature field
                    setState(() {
                      temperatureField = true;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      temperatureField = false;
                    });
                  }
                  if (volumeItemTypes
                      .contains(itemTypeController.text.trim())) {
                    //show temperature field
                    setState(() {
                      volumeField = true;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      volumeField = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: itemTypeController,
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Item type*",
                    hintText: 'What is the item?',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but can't you just use hintText from Input decaration to show initial value, just as you did?

Comment: User cant edit hint text @EmreFarukKOLAÇ